# users/*/playlists not returning starred/collaborative playlists

Tags: spotify

Last week calls to users/{user_id}/playlists returned a complete list of the users playlists, which included:

- their own starred playlists
- starred playlists they subscribe too
- collaborative playlists they created/subscribed to

Now, this endpoint doesn't seem to return **any of these** items.

For example, I have a playlist which returns fine UNTIL I change it to be collaborative... then it is no longer in the response.

I have tested this with various combinations of scope authentication.

Answer (score 2):

The /users/{user_id}/playlists endpoint is not guaranteed to return starred tracks. We'll add a specific endpoint to retrieve starred tracks in a very near future, and we'll announce the changes in the [change log](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/change-log/).

Collaborative playlists are never returned regardless of scope, which is the current intended behaviour. This is covered in the [documentation for users/{user_id}/playlists](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-list-users-playlists/).

> Note that a user's collaborative playlists are not currently
>   retrievable.

We're doing a lot of thinking about how to allow developers to work with collaborative playlists, so please stay tuned for news on the Developer site.

Comment: Thank you Michael.

It seems counter-intuitive to have a separate endpoint for starred & collaborative playlists. Especially when the playlist objects already have a "collaborative" Boolean property.

Just my $.02